# Reason why a freed TStringList counts as memory leak in the FastMM4 report

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-2010, tstringlist, fastmm

After noticing an odd memory behavior in task manager in one of my applications I started investigating memory leaks with FastMM4.
I found more than 1000 just after opening three forms.
I hope I will be able to find the cause in a single place

In one case, even if always free the TStringList in the finally block (that is always reached), FastMM4 reports a memory leak:

```
function GetMatchingResourceFileName(MatchingString:string) : string;
var
  ResourcesList: TStringList;
  I : Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    ResourcesList := TStringList.Create;
    // get resource files list
    ResourcesList := GetResourceList;
    //search for matching file name
    for I := 0 to ResourcesList.Count-1 do
    begin
      if Pos(MatchingString,ResourcesList.Strings[I]) > 0 then
      begin
        Result := ResourcesList.Strings[I];
        break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    ResourcesList.Free;
    ResourcesList:= nil;
  end;
end;
```

FastMM4 stack report tells me that the leak starts from

```
ResourcesList := TStringList.Create;
```

even if I am 100% sure that `ResourcesList.Free;` is executed I see the memory leak.

Here you can see that the breakpoint is hit:
[image: breakpoint being hit]

As I close the app I see the report:

```
---------------------------
myProject.exe: Memory Leak Detected
---------------------------
This application has leaked memory. The small-block leaks are (excluding expected leaks registered by pointer):



85 - 100 bytes: System.Classes.TStringList x 1



Note: Memory leak detail is logged to a text file in the same folder as this application. To disable this memory leak check, undefine "EnableMemoryLeakReporting".
```

To study the leak above I commented 99% of my code focus on the first reported leak, in fact, one in the initialization part of the app.

How this is possible?

**Update**

The working version of the code avoids to call `TStringList.Create` since the `GetResourceList` method already returns a properly created `TStringList`, the following code is now leak free:

```
function GetMatchingResourceFileName(MatchingString:string) : string;
var
  ResourcesList: TStringList;
  I : Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    ResourcesList := GetResourceList;
    //search for matching file name
    for I := 0 to ResourcesList.Count-1 do
[...]
```

Comment: It is not useful to answer your own question in an "Update", as you do above, especially when that update still shows erroneous coding practice (refer to "2" in the answer). There is a good reason that posts are distinctly either **questions** or **answers**.

Comment: You are allowed to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two problems:

## 1

```pascal
1.    ResourcesList := TStringList.Create;
2.    // get resource files list
3.    ResourcesList := GetResourceList;
```

On line 1, you create a new `TStringList` object and save the address to this in the local `ResourcesList` variable.

But on line 3, I suppose the `GetResourceList` function also creates a new `TStringList` object, and then you rewrite the local `ResourcesList` variable so that it points to this, new, object instead.

This means that there now is *no variable* pointing to the first `TStringList` object you created. Hence, it is forever leaked.

What you want is this:

```pascal
    // get resource files list
    ResourcesList := GetResourceList;
```

## 2

Your code is essentially

```pascal
try
  ResourcesList := TStringList.Create; //or GetResourceList;
  // Use the list
finally
  ResourcesList.Free
end;
```

This is a very common bug. If the `TStringList.Create` constructor fails (or the `GetResourceList` function), the partially created `TStringList` object is automatically freed (or hopefully freed by the `GetResourceList` function), but then the exception stops the execution, so no value is written to `ResourcesList`.

Hence, `ResourcesList.Free` will then run the destructor on a random pointer, since local variables of unmanaged types are not initialized.

You *must* do

```pascal
ResourcesList := TStringList.Create; //or GetResourceList;
try
  // Use the list
finally
  ResourcesList.Free
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact you are right: `GetResourceList ` returns a TStringList that is created in that method and this explains the memory leak. Thanks also for the point number (2): this is something I am aware and I usually write the create out of the try block, but dealing with legacy code I see both approaches used. by the way this TStringList leak is a minor one, I'll keep on searching to  find the big one that is causing big memory errors in my application.

Comment: @LaBracca you might want to use a tool for this task like EurekaLog or MadExcept

Comment: If you use the full version of FastMM, you can co figure it to log where the leaked allocations are occurring.